# python tkinter disable line break in text widget

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

In the code below, I am looking for a way to disable the line break in a Text widget. I would simply have used an Entry widget however, Entry has no UNDO functionality.

When I press enter in the Text widget, the parse function is called as required but it also goes to the next line.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

#

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        self.master = Tk()
        self.master.geometry("300x200")

        Frame.__init__(self, self.master)
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.master.bind('<Return>', self.parse)
        self.grid()

        w1 = Text(self, undo=True, height=1, width=26,wrap=NONE)
        w1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)

        self.submit = Button(self, text="Submit")
        self.submit.bind('<Button-1>', self.parse)
        self.submit.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=E)

    def parse(self, event):
        print("You clicked?")

    def start(self):
        self.master.mainloop()


Application().start()
```

Comment: don't forget that users can also paste code into a text widget, so you'll need to handle the case where they paste in something with a newline.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `return 'break'` at the end of your event binding to keep Tkinter from doing its default action:

```
def parse(self, event):
    print("You clicked?")
    return 'break'
```

You'll also need to bind the return to the entry specifically:

```
w1 = Text(self, undo=True, height=1, width=26,wrap=NONE)
w1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)
w1.bind('<Return>', self.parse)
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that but it only works when the cursor is at the beginning of the string, if I place it anywhere else in the Text widget and press ENTER it inserts a line break as before.

Answer (score 0):

Use [string.strip(s[, chars])](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) in your parse function, like this:

```
from Tkinter import *

START = "1.0"
END = "end"

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        self.master = Tk()
        self.master.geometry("300x200")

        Frame.__init__(self, self.master)
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        self.w1 = Text(self, undo=True, height=1, width=26,wrap=NONE)
        self.w1.bind("<Return>", self.parse)

        self.submit = Button(self, text="Submit")
        self.submit.bind('<Button-1>', self.parse)

        self.grid()
        self.w1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)
        self.submit.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=E)

    def parse(self, event):
        parsed_str = self.w1.get(START, END).strip()
        self.w1.delete(START, END)
        print parsed_str

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myapp = Application()
    myapp.mainloop()
```